# Рисование графа

Tags: графы, алгоритм, php, графика, canvas

Нужно нарисовать граф с 1000+ вершинами и вывести на канву. Есть алгоритм [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_(graph_drawing))

Мне нужна помощь в его реализации. Вершины графа задаются ребрами:

1 2
1 3
1 8
2 1
2 3
2 5
3 1
3 2
3 5
3 8
4 6
4 8
5 2
5 3
5 6
6 4
6 5
8 1
8 3
8 4

Comment: Что такое граф ?
Он может быть настолько сложным, что графическое отображение его бессмысленно(сотни перекрёстных ссылок, ссылок на массива и пр). Чтото в бесполезной матчасти, которую в вузах преподают - тогда хз, зачем это нужно и что это такое.

Answer (score 2):

Для изображения графов, сетей, их красивой разводки
прекрасно подойдет библиотека [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html).
Есть реализации для Java и .NET.

Библиотека платная, но для учебных целей подойдет и 30-дневная пробная версия.

Comment: А вообще, что надо-то? Помощь в реализации Force-based algorithms (graph drawing) или надо что-то, что выводило бы изображения графов? Во втором случае есть ответ graphviz (утилита такая - точнее несколько утилит)